# Minimum support and minimum confidence in Data Mining

Tags: data-mining, apriori

I would like to know if minimum support and minimum confidence can be automatically determined in mining association rules? If so any hint or pointer to resource would be great.

Comment: Obviously minimum support is 1, and minimum confidence is 0...

Comment: In general, minsup and minconf are defined in the [0,1] interval.  But I think that it is not the question here. I think that he wants to know if an algorithm can set these parameters automatically to some values that will find the patterns that he wants. Setting minsup to 1 in a [0,1] interval may miss a lot of patterns since only rules appearing in all transactions would be output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there exist some method to automatically determine the minsup and minconf threshold.

But first, let me tell you a little bit about how to choose the minsup and minconf parameters. Choosing them depends on your data.

For the **minimum support**, I use 80 % on some data. For some other data, I use 0.05 %. It all depends on the dataset. Usually, I start with a high value, and then I decrease the values until I find a value that will generate enough patterns.

For the **min. confidence**, it is a little bit easier because it represents the confidence that you want in the rules. So usually, I use something like 60 % because I'm not interested in a rule that is truly less than 60 % of the time. But it also depends on the data.

In terms of performance, when minsup is higher you will find less pattern and the algorithm is faster.  For minconf, when it is set higher, there will be less pattern but it may not be faster because many algorithms don't use minconf to prune the search space. So obviously, setting these parameters also depends on how many rules you want.

If you don't want to use the minsup parameter you can use a **top-k association rule mining algorithm**. In this case, you will specify k=1000 for instance and the algorithm will discover the 1000  most frequent rules with given minimum confidence. I have designed one such algorithm named **TopKRules** for association rule mining. You can download the source code from the [SPMF open-source data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/), which offers many implementations of association rule and pattern mining algorithm.

Another solution to set the minsup threshold automatically is to use a mathematical function to set it in terms of how much data you have. You can see my [blog post here](http://data-mining.philippe-fournier-viger.com/how-to-auto-adjust-the-minimum-support-threshold-according-to-the-data-size/) as an example of how to do it.

Some other works have attempted to find a solution to setting minsup and minconf. You may find them on Google Scholar.